# How to retrieve TextView data from another Java class / activity

Tags: java, android, textview

I have two Java classes. Where I want to retrieve `TextView` data from `DrinkDetail.java` into `Cart.java` in order to save it into `Firebase database`. The `TextView` is `deliveryOption` and wanted to save in `Cart.java` from Requests table.

How can I do it? Below are my Java codes.

**`DrinkDetail.java`**

```
public class DrinkDetail extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink_detail);

private void showAlertDialogChooseOptions() {
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DrinkDetail.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Drop by our kiosk or rider deliver?");

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View takeaway_deliver = inflater.inflate(R.layout.takeaway_delivery, null);

    btnTakeAway = (FButton)takeaway_deliver.findViewById(R.id.btnTakeAway);
    btnDelivery = (FButton)takeaway_deliver.findViewById(R.id.btnDelivery);
    deliveryOption = (TextView)takeaway_deliver.findViewById(R.id.deliveryOptionChosen);

    alertDialog.setView(takeaway_deliver);
    alertDialog.create();

    btnTakeAway.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deliveryOption.setText("Take Away");
            alertDialogTakeAway.show();
        }
    });
}
```

**`Cart.java:`**

```
public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

private void showAlertDialog() {
    alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Cart.this);
    alertDialog2.setTitle("Cash on Delivery:");
    alertDialog2.setMessage("Choose amount of money will be given to the rider upon order arriving: ");

    LayoutInflater inflater2 = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View cash_on_delivery = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.cash_on_delivery, null);

    btnOrderNow = (FButton)cash_on_delivery.findViewById(R.id.btnOrderNow);
    btnOrderNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Submit to Firebase
            Request request = new Request(
                    Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
                    Common.currentUser.getName(),
                    editAddress.getText().toString(),
                    txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
                    "0", //status
                    editComment.getText().toString(),
                    paymentMethod.getText().toString(),
                    moneySelected.getText().toString(),
                    //WANTED TO SAVE DELIVERY OPTION "TAKE AWAY" HERE,
                    cart
            );
            requests.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .setValue(request);

            //Order placed
            alertDialogOrderPlaced.show();
            alertDialog2.setCancelable(true);
        }
    });

    alertDialog2.setView(cash_on_delivery);
    alertDialog2.setIcon(R.drawable.icons8_cash_in_hand_filled_50);
}
```

Comment: How you are navigating from DrinkDetail to Cart activity?

Comment: Store your TextView value into SharedPreferences in DrinkDetail.java and Retrieve it in cart.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To send the data from one activity to another activity
>
> `DrinkDetail.java` is first activity from where you want to send data
>   to another activity

**DrinkDetail.java**

```
TextView aText = (TextView )findViewById(R.id.textview);
String text = aText .getText().toString();

Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Cart.java);
myIntent.putExtra("mytext",text);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

> `Cart.java` is second activity which receive the `Intent` data whatever
>   you pass from `DrinkDetail.java`

**Cart.java**

```
public class Cart extends Activity {

TextView mTextview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.Cart);

    aTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    aTextview.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("mytext"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a public method in the class you want to retrieve the data from. Like `getData()`, something similar to this:

```
public Data getData(){
   return this.data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Data can be stored  using `SharedPreferences`.
In your `DrinkDetail.java` save the data.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("File", MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("deliveryOption", deliveryOption.getText()).apply();
```

In your `Cart.java` you can retrieve it back.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("File", MODE_PRIVATE);
String deliveryOption = prefs.getString("deliveryOption", "default");
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using `Intent` to navigate from DrinkDetail to Cart then you can pass that string in `Intent` itself.

like this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(DrinkDetail.this, Cart.class);
intent.putExtra("Key","String value you want to pass");
startActivity(intent);
```

and can retrieve that string in `Cart.java` place below code in `onCreate()` method

```
String value;
if(getIntent()!=null) 
    value=getIntent().getStringExtra("Key");
```